# Transform/change/convert rotation axis

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I would like to know what mechanical parts can be used to convert a rotation movement from an axis to another.

For example: You have the shaft of a motor rotating vertically, but you need to rotate a part horizontally.

I already found the worm drive assembly but I would like to know if an "exhaustive" list exists somewhere with pro/con for each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The go-to solution is [bevel gears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bevel_gear). They are used when the shafts would intersect and allow the same ratios as normal gears.

You can also make one of the gears a [crown gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_gear) so the other gear can be a normal spur gear.

A [universal joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_joint) is also an option if the angle isn't too big.

Comment: Are there existing belt based solutions ? I'm a little bit worried by backlash that could be added by bevel gears.

Comment: There is backlash in belts too as the tension is transfered to the other side of the belt. But you can use cones as friction gears.